# What do I need to prepare for if I am making a trip out of state from New York?

Tags: covid-19, new-york-state, maryland

I'm planning to make a trip from New York to Maryland to attend my father's retirement - it's scheduled to take place in September.

Recently, Maryland was added to the [list of travel-restricted states](https://www.governor.ny.gov/news/governor-cuomo-announces-individuals-traveling-new-york-eight-additional-states-will-be) for New York.

These travel restrictions are put in place for visitors coming from another state to New York - but I am a native New Yorker.  What should I prepare for when I return from Maryland?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As of this writing, travelers entering New York from one of the listed states must [fill out the traveler health form](https://coronavirus.health.ny.gov/covid-19-travel-advisory) (on paper if arriving by air or [online](https://forms.ny.gov/s3/Welcome-to-New-York-State-Traveler-Health-Form) if arriving by other means) *and then quarantine for fourteen days* upon arrival in New York. These rules apply equally to visitors and New York residents returning home.

It should be noted that the situation is subject to change between now and September, and states could be added or removed, or any other aspect of the program could be modified.